# Correct way parsing a text file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a text file that is coming is some predefined way.
I don't have something like it's xsd, but the pattern can be seen.

for example it looks something like this:

```
[MyFIRSTPARAGRAPH]
NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 NUM4 NUM5 NUM6 NUM7 NUM8 NUM9 NUM10 NUM11
1 1 0.000 0.000 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
2 2 22.800 0.000 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
3 3 45.600 0.000 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
4 4 68.400 0.000 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
5 5 91.200 0.000 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
6 6 0.000 32.800 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
7 7 22.800 32.800 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
8 8 45.600 32.800 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
9 9 68.400 32.800 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
10 10 91.200 32.800 0.000 0 1 1 0 0 ""
```

A lot paragraphs separated by space lines.

Any saggestion what it the best what to parse files like this and to extract the values from the text.

Comment: This looks like a private case, what's the deal with writing your own parser? that text looks pretty simple to be parsed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My very first guess would be to do something like this:

```
using(var reader = GetStreamReader())
{
    bool justReadATag = false;
    string line = string.Empty;

    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(IsTag(line)) 
        {
            // do some work with the paragraph tag
            justReadATag = true;
        }else{
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if(justReadATag) 
            {
                // do some work with the column names
                justReadATag = false;    
            }else
            {
                // do some work with the cell values
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest read the complete file using `File.ReadAllLines` method. Now you can iterate all the lines one by one. Then for each line use `String.Split(' ')` to get the values which are separated by space in the line